# Is a difference between Chrome and HTML Viewer?

Tags: android, html, webview

I have an HTML page which I downloaded (save as) in my computer. I loaded the same in the android asset folder and in the webview, i was trying to load the saved HTML page. The HTML page is not fitting in the webview properly. I used the following code:

```
        WebView webView = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webView);
         //Enable Java scripts
    //   webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//       webView.setInitialScale(100);
         //webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
         webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
         webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
         webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
         webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        //webview.setInitialScale(100); No need for this one
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
```

Now, I had referred many stackoverflow discussions but, none of them helped. The width of the web page is fitting, however, the height is not. There are lots of blank spaces below the page which i loaded. The layout xml is as below:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

I tried to call the website directly from chrome in my android device and the web page is brilliantly fit in the screen. But, the same in the web view is not.

I tried to open the saved html page in HTML viewer and the same happens. Whats the difference here? Please can someone help me on how to fit the web page in the view? Why is there a difference ONLY in the height of the page?

Regards,
Hari